# Google Cloud request : 301 error on curl but works on browser

Tags: google-app-engine, curl, cron, google-cloud-platform

I created a GAE service on the cloud.
also created a dispatch.yaml.

```
dispatch:
  - url: "*/cron/*"
    service: myservice
```

I also defined an handler on `myservice` at `/cron/start` on my webserver listening to `0.0.0.0/8080`

cron.yaml

```
cron:
- description: "pull transactions"
  url: /cron/start
  schedule: every 5 minutes
```

I used the url :

> https://my-project-id.appspot.com/cron/start

the cron doesn't work. 
I tried to use the url on Chrome Webbrowser - Works fine.

I tried to use curl :

```
curl -X GET https://my-project-id.appspot.com/cron/start
```

I am getting a xml:

```
<a href="https://my-project-id.appspot.com/cron/start">Moved Permanently</a>.
```

Can someone please explain what is happening on those different agents? i.e cron, Chrome Browser, curl

Comment: When Chrome receives a redirect, it will follow the redirect - meaning that Chrome will go to the new location automatically. If you open the Chrome debugger (press F-12 and then reload the page) you will see this happening.

Comment: The 301 HTTP response indeed means that the request is redirected. Can you explain in more detail what is happening to the cron job? Are there any errors in the logs? Share more details so that we could assist with the cron job issue.